# shell-write command problem - How to add a "key" to a plist file via terminal? (iphone,mobileterminal)

Tags: iphone, shell, terminal, key, plist

I wanted to run this command in mobileterminal (iphone):

```
write "/myPlist.plist" TestKey "TestStringForKey"
```

but it says: `'write' command not found`

The plist EXISTS!

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other way?

EDIT: TestKey does not exist in the plist. I want to create it.

EDIT: Some infos: iPod Touch with iOS 4.2.1 and with the newest mobileterminal from googlecode.

EDIT: Now I installed "write".
If I run the command i get this: `usage: write user [tty]`

Comment: you mean "write - command not found"? That's weird. write is located at /usr/bin/write, what does "which write" say when you type it in your terminal?

Comment: not working yet...anyone with a solution that works?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `defaults` command:

```
defaults write "myPlist.plist" TestKey "TestStringForKey"
```

Comment: output: "sh: defaults: command not found" (without quotes""")

Answer (score 1):

I use this to write to a plist file with iPhone terminal. Just make sure you have ericautilities installed from Cydia.

```
plutil -key ShowedAlert -value nope /dir/ect/ory/to/playlist.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

/myPlist.plist means, that myPlist.plist is in your root directory. I think, it's in your current working directory, so just use

```
write "myPlist.plist" TestKey "TestStringForKey"
```

Comment: type "which write" in your terminal. what's the output?

Comment: there's no output. (I'm doing all this stuff as root user)

Comment: This file does not exist:/usr/bin/write

Comment: I installed "BigBoss Recommended" from cydia and now it works! the "write" file exists!

Comment: but every time I type in the command it says: "usage: write user [tty]"